# Go up/come down: Do both phrases imply the same thing on a fundamental level in the given context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

The number of articles I've written so far this month is 47. If I can manage to write 10 more, that number will **go up** to 57.

The number of articles I've written so far this month is 47. If I can manage to write 10 more, that number will **come down** to 57.

Do both **go up** and **come down** work in this sentence? I, as a non-native speaker, believe they do. **Go up** in the first sentence stresses on the increase from 47 to 57, whereas **come down** in the second sentence focuses on what the number will eventually be, which in this case would be 57.

Are both sentences grammatically correct? Can we use **come down** to talk about an increase in a figure?

Comment: If a number 'comes down', it is _reduced_.

Comment: A sentence can be grammatically correct but meaningless. It would be unidiomatic to refer to a number that has increased 'coming down' - native speakers would find it very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we say a number 'comes down' to a value, we mean that it is reduced from some previous higher value.

If we say a number 'goes up' to a value, we mean that is increased from some previous lower value.

In either case the previous or new values are not necessarily stated.

> Due to sickness, the number of students attending the class has come
> down to 15.
>
> The number of rabbits has gone up.

You may be thinking of an idiom, 'come down to' meaning 'to have a particular thing as the most important matter'. Often this is said as the final thing or item in a discussion or statement, e.g. we have thought about where we shall take our holiday next year, and It all comes down to money in the end.

[Come down to something (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-down-to-something)